# transition doesn't work editing while window onload

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to move this square to right 100px after clicking on it with js, I've set the transition to 1s, but it doesn't work

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var square = document.querySelector(".square");        
    square.onclick = function(){
        square.style.right = "100px";
    };
};
```

```css
.square {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS won't animate things from `auto` to `px`.
Since `right` is not defined, it's defaulting to `auto`.

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var square = document.querySelector(".square");        
    square.onclick = function(){
        square.style.right = "100px";
    };
};
```

```css
.square {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    right: 0;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
</div>
```

However, if you want to animate it without setting `right` at the beginning, you can also use `translate`.

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var square = document.querySelector(".square");        
    square.onclick = function(){
        square.style.transform = "translateX(100px)";
    };
};
```

```css
.square {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
</div>
```